# meta title and name doesn't ender quote laravel

Tags: html, laravel, meta

Hello I'm trying to render meta tag and description dynamically. I have following layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<!-- Title -->
<title>@yield('title')</title>

<!-- Meta -->
<meta name="description" content="@yield('description', 'Meta default description')">
```

I get result
like '
here is my screenshot of result

[image]

How to render the datas inside double quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `@yield,@section,@include,etc` is a **Blade Templating**.

`@yield` only paramater for added `content` from `@section` example `@yield('title')` will call from `@section('title','Added Title')`

So if you will added a double content, you can try with parameter like this:

`<meta name="description" content="@yield('description', 'Meta default description')">`

Then added in blade calling this Blade like

```
@extends('layouts.index')
@section('description', __('Call The Meta, New'))
@section('content')
```

After you running it, from `Meta default description` will change to `Call The Meta, New`
Like

`<meta name="description" content="Call The Meta, New">`

Because firstly, `Meta default description` default meta.